# How to show hidden columns in Excel chart by default?

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I have a large workbook which generates charts on demand and then deletes them after viewing, then generating a new chart if needed, etc.

I would like to have the "Show Hidden Data" switch turned on by default, as there are many columns of data I wish to hide in the worksheet that are used in the charts. I know I can select this through ChartTools -> Design -> Data but you have to do it for every chart de novo. I cannot get the macro recorder to capture the VBA commands.

Is there a way to code this in VBA when I generate the chart?
Thank you.

Comment: I was not asking to hide a column. In Excel, if you generate a chart, then hide one of the data columns, the series disappears UNLESS you change the "Show Hidden Data" switch. But this only works for an individual chart and must be changed for each subsequent chart. I needed to change the setting programmatically in VBA. The code that works is below.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, this is the code:

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("chart_name_here").Activate
    ActiveChart.PlotVisibleOnly = False

Works on my tests.